# ActiveMQ failover for stomp over websocket

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

Is there a workaround to implement an activemq failover for stomp over websocket?

The uri in my web browser is **ws://localhost:61614/stomp** which is working fine. But adding **failover:(ws://localhost:61614/stomp)** will not work.

Appreciate any guidance.

Regards,

Walter

Answer (score 2):

The failover transport only works with ActiveMQ's openwire based protocol.  For stomp you need to handle all exceptions and reconnect when something goes wrong.

Comment: It seems like your suggestion is the practical option. Thanks Tim.

Comment: Is this still true for ActiveMQ 5.11?

Comment: Yes, websocket connections don't really make sense from a Java application.

Comment: this was also my feeling that failover is only working with some protocols (e.g. openwire) but not with others. However I found [this page](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/stomp/uri-configuration) where it seems supported for stomp by using the NMS client (.NET)

Comment: Then I am curious (as this post is quite old) if an url like `stomp:failover:(tcp://server01:61613,tcp://server02:61613)` would work with a classic java client

Comment: The ActiveMQ java client only speaks openwire, no stomp